# Linking html <input> and <output> with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have this code which basically does a simple math function but now I do not know how to link the `<input>` and the `<output>` tags with the JavaScript so that when users put a digit in `<input>` the script is run and the result is displayed in the `<output>`
Any help is appreciated and please be helpful as I am still learning.

```js
function computation(number) { 
  let newNumber = number + (1/100 * number) + 1000;
  let roundedNumber = Math.round(newNumber/100)*100;
  return roundedNumber;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter Amount Here:</p>
<input type="text" name="value"></input>
<button class="button" onClick="computation()">Calculate!</button>
<p>Final Amount</p>
<div class="output">
    <output for="roundedNumber" name="finalAmount"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: use a `script` tag and in the `src` attribute give the path of the external `JS` file

Comment: Linking means what? What you want to do with this code?

Comment: @CoolJK basicaly i want when the number is input in the `<input>` then the script should run and the final answer should be given out in the `<output>`

Comment: @PaulH maybe not but the script should run when the input is made and the result should be given in the <output>

Answer (score 2):

Follow below simple steps.
1) Add ids to your input and output tags, just put same as name

```
<input type="text" name="value" id="value" />
<output for="roundedNumber" name="finalAmount" id="finalAmount"/>
```

2) use js `document.getElementById("inputid").value`

```
let num = document.getElementById("value").value
```

3) use the same way to set value. lets assume u want to show it in paragraph tag.

```
<p id="output"></p>
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =newNum;
```

4) for active tags use `.value` instant of `.innerHTML`

Comment: Please give some meaningful values to ur name and id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are having number as a parameter to function but function is not getting it when you call it.So you can use

```
document.getElementById('id').value
```

to get the value.
Have a look at this.

```js
function computation() { 
  let number = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  let newNumber = number + (1/100 * number) + 1000;
  let roundedNumber = Math.round(newNumber/100) * 100;
  document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = roundedNumber;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter Amount Here:</p><br>
<input type="text" name="value1" id="input1">
<button class="button" onClick="computation()">Calculate!</button>
<p>Final Amount</p>
<div class="output">
<output for="roundedNumber" name="finalAmount" id="output1"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a really nice solution although it doesn't  do what I originally intended it but I think I can fix that. Thanks!